# Wordpress - How to allow subscribers to change their password without Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, passwords, dashboard

My subscribers have no need to access the Dashboard after they sign up to my site, so I have disabled it from appearing at the top of the page for them. However it means that currently they won't be able to change the initial password that is emailed to them.

Is there any way I can add a password-change functionality to the My Account section of the site, so they can change their password on-site without having to access the Dashboard? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function [wp_set_password](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password) will reset the user's password.  You just need to build a form to get the new password from the user then call this function.